# Displaying :datetime math

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with a column called **start** and typed as :datetime.

I would like to be able to calculate how many days there are until the **start** date and time.

Currently, I have a simple view that does

```
<%= @myModel.start - Time.now %>
```

This gives me something like -650.878217378

1. How can I get it to display days and hours until that date
2. It seems wrong to be doing this in the view - should I make another instance variable for this calc in my view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `distance_of_time_in_words` / `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now` view helpers will produce human friendly strings, see the [rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) for examples.

If you are going to be doing calculations like this and the rails provided view helpers don;t meet your needs, I'd write my own view helpers. I don't think there's anything 'naughty' about doing

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(@myModel.start) %>
```

Comment: This works much better than what I had, and very easy. I'll have to look into how to display it with a bit more granularity - ie. Days and Hours and may need to open a new question for that. Thanks!